# Spring boot: send an email based on a time in the database

Tags: spring-boot

I'm developing a mini project with spring boot for the creation of a calendar in which any registered user can add events to his calendar.
When an event is entered the user also selects a time, as a last feature I would like to implement an automatic sending of an email 30 minutes before the start time. Is it possible to do this with `@Scheduled` annotation?

Answer (score 1):

The [@Scheduled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) annotation accepts a cron string or a delay/rate value (the logic is different, see [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks) Baeldung tutorial).

You can schedule a task every minute to perform a query on db/calendar and check if it is the correct time to send the email. You can add `@Cacheable` annotations to improve performance.